# How to change values of parameter "filter" in url with regular expression dynamically?

Tags: java, regex, replace

I want in addresse string using regular expression (regex) e.g.

```
http://test.ru/mydomen.com/category/23:detskij-tekstilq/85:postelqnoe-belqe/orderby=pricedesc/filter=countries:0,1;vendors:0,2,3/
```

find parameter "filter" and change it values in dynamically.

e.g. on

```
http://test.ru/mydomen.com/category/23:detskij-tekstilq/85:postelqnoe-belqe/orderby=pricedesc/filter=vendors:0,2,3;sizes:0,1/
```

My experiment is (failed) :

```
current_url.replace(/\?filter=([a-z0-9\-]+)\&?/, new_values+'/');
```

How can I do it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your experiment is pretty close already.

```
// wrong:
current_url.replace(/\?filter=([a-z0-9\-]+)\&?/, new_values+'/');
// correct:
current_url.replace(/\bfilter=([a-z0-9\-]+)\b/, new_values+'/');
```

There is no `?` in front of the word `filter`, but your regex was looking for one. Using `\b` (word boundary) is better anyway.

Comment: I use it in java. Sorry, but it not working for me! Thank you.

Comment: @AndriySkolozhabskiy What do you mean by it's not working now? Can you show what it's giving you and what you are expecting?

Comment: On submit form (id="filyter-form") I get all input values to hidden input e.g. filter=countries:0,1;vendors:0,2,3. Onward I get current parameter "action" from form  as $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and now I should find in url parameter "filter" and to change it value to new value, e.g. filter=vendors:0,2,3;sizes:0,1. But it not working!

Comment: It is working: location.href = action + $('#hidden_field').val()+'/', but added sting filter to old parameter filter; But it is not working: location.href = action.replace(/\bfilter=([a-z0-9\-]+)\b/, $('#hidden_field').val()+'/');